# d/dx of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int\limits_{-17}^{ln (x)} e^{3t-4} \, dt =$$

I got $$\frac{1}{x}e^{3ln\left(x\right)-4}$$ because I plugged in ln(x) for t and took the derivate of ln x as well is this right

Comment: This is correct, although (1) $\frac 1x e^{3 ln x - 4}$ can be simplified further (2) $e^{3t-4}$ has an easy anti-derivative so if you had trouble with the chain rule framework you could have just integrated the function and then differentiated the result anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your anser is correct.

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and $\phi,\psi$
are differentiable functions then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\psi(x)}^{\phi(x)}f(t)dt=
f(\phi(x))\frac{d\phi}{dx}-f(\psi(x))\frac{d\psi}{dx}.
$$

Applying this to your problem (I will go really slow here):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int\limits_{-17}^{ln (x)} e^{3t-4} \, dt =
e^{3\ln{x}-4}\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln{x}=
e^{\ln{x^3}-4}\,\frac{1}{x}=
e^{-4}e^{\ln{x^3}}\,\frac{1}{x}=
e^{-4}\frac{x^3}{x}=e^{-4}x^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $F(x) = \int_{-17}^x e^{3t-4}\,dt$. Then $F'(x) = e^{3x-4}$ and, using the chain rule,
$$
\frac d{dx}\int_{-17}^{\ln(x)} e^{3t-4}\,dt = \frac d{dx}F(\ln(x)) = F'(\ln(x))\ln'(x) = e^{3\ln(x)-4}\cdot\frac 1x = e^{-4}x^2.
$$